# Merging two audio files with sox while adjusting their volume

Tags: audio, merge, sox

Merging two audio files can be done with `sox`:

```
sox -m input1.wav input2.wav output.wav
```

How adjusting the volume of one the input files can be applied in this single command. It is obvious that this can be accomplished by two command like these:

```
sox -v 0.7 input.wav output.wav
sox -m input1.wav output.wav output2.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. The `-v` option can be applied to each input file, and for any of the combine methods. Set the scale factor in front of the file you want it applied to.

```
sox -n -r 44100 -b 16 s660.wav synth 20 sine 660 # a pure A
sox -n -r 44100 -b 16 s440.wav synth 20 sine 440 # a pure E

sox -m -v 0.4 s440.wav -v 0.9 s660.wav mix4-9.wav # an A5 with weight on the prime
sox -m -v 0.9 s440.wav -v 0.4 s660.wav mix9-4.wav # an A5 with weight on the fifth
```